# Prop. A finite intersection of open sets is open.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Prop. A finite intersection of open sets is open.

Proof. Suppose that $\left\{ A_{i}\subset \mathbb{R} :i=1,\ldots ,n\right\}$ is finite collection of open sets. If $x\in \cap _{i=1}^{n}A_{i}$, then $x\in A_{i}$ for every $1\leq i\leq n$. Since $A_{i}$ is open, there is $\delta_{i}>0$ such that $A_{i}\supset \left( x- \delta_{i},x+ \delta _i\right)$. Let

$\delta =\min \left( \delta_{1},\delta_{2},\ldots ,\delta_{n}\right)$. Then, $\cap _{i=1}^{n}A_{i}\supset \left( x- \delta ,x+ \delta\right)$.

Question: Why we chose min to $\delta$? Why we used $\delta$ instead of $\delta _i$ in context?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Are you asking only why the symbol $\delta$ is used rather than the symbol $\delta_i$?

Comment: In every context where $i$ is used, $i$ denotes an arbitrary number from $1$ to $n$. In your expression $\delta_i$, what exactly is $i$ equal to?

Comment: The $\delta_i$ are already chosen.  You want ONE value for $\delta$ that does the job, as the minimum does.

Comment: The question was edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is more easily understood when considering the intersection of only two open sets. Consider open sets $U$ and $V$. Since they are open, for each $x\in U$ there exists $\epsilon_1$ such that $I_{\epsilon_1}(x)$ is contained in $U$. Also, for each $x\in V$ there exists $\epsilon_2$ such that $I_{\epsilon _2 }(x)$ is contained in $V$. Now choosing $\delta = \min(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)$ we see that for each $x\in U\cap V$,  $I_{\delta}(x)$ is contained in $U\cap V$. It is clear that this argument extends to a finite intersection.

*$I_\epsilon (x)$ is an open interval of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $x$.